# rails 4.2 tinyMCE gem produces failed to load content css skins/lightgray/content.min.css

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tinymce-4

I just introduced tinyMCE into my rails 4.2.8 site to let manage formatted text in articles. Everything works fine actually but now and then a warning message produced by tinyMCE comes up such as "failed to load content css: http://myurl/assets/tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.min.css" but if a look at the debug console in firefox I see that url has perfectly found and loaded content.min.css.

When the warning message is there I can't enter anything in the textarea but the situation is fixed by reloading the page, then the rich text can be nicely entered and the relevant data is loaded correctly into the backend DB via relevant input form.

I don't understand the reason why tinyMCE is signalling such a warning despite the fact that the css file was actually found.

Any idea? Thanks and kind regards
Vincenzo

**** update on June 8th 2017 ****
Now I can better explain what's actually going on.

1) the problem shows up in Firefox v.53, if I use Chrome everything works fine

2) I am using tinyMCE in three distinct forms: one for new articles, one for editing, one for comments.

3) If I insert a few new articles no problem appears, the problem shows up just chenging the form in use: i.e. after insertion an article I try editing it or another one or else I try to insert a comment after havine inserted a new article. After the error message has shown I can always recover by reloading the page and no error appears eventually.

I guess there is some caching problem specifically in Firefox since all works fine in Chrome. I will try Windows Edge too..

2017/06/10
Tried Windows Edge on Win10: it works fine too.

2017/06/14
In the meantime I opened bug 1371910 at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1371910#c5 a few days ago and the result was: 
QUOTE
Hi Vincenzo,
Thanks for sending us the link. Unfortunately this seems to be a problem with tinyMCE rather than Firefox.
The initial load of content.min.css works correctly, and no other attempts to reload it seem to be made.
If it works in other browsers it is probably due to the developers doing things differently.

If you still think this is a bug in Firefox, please reopen this bug, and send us a smaller test case.

PS. Others seem to be having the same problem as you: https://community.tinymce.com/communityQuestion?id=90661000000Qct9AAC
I hope you find a way to fix it.
UNQUOTE

What the Firefox support says makes sense since I too whatched the content.min.css file was actually loaded by the browser so in must be tinyMCE to misinterpret something. Anyway I am still in the soup...
Whoever might have some interest at this issue please hava a look at:
http://vinloren-learn-rails.herokuapp.com/articles accessing this endpoint with Firefox v52..v54 the click show any article then going back via the 'back' link at the end of the article's content.

Comment: Can you post a link to the gem? Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: Hi Niklas, yes I am using turbolinks, the gem is tinymce-rails (4.6.3) bundled in my installation.

Comment: I have the same issue, here's the plunk http://embed.plnkr.co/6QCok7akLU0rJtjOc2Eg/ open the dialog, close, and open again, and u will get error